# Как получить все службы доставки, которые привязаны к местоположению?

Tags: php, битрикс

подскажите как в битриксе получить все службы доставки, которые привязаны к местоположению?
т.е есть locationId по нему я могу получить службы, но id выдаются странные вида:

```
Array(
[0] => 2
[1] => 3
[2] => new122:profile
[3] => new200:profile
)
```

первые две это ид службы а вторые профили видимо от служб, как правильно вытащить все службы по этим профилям? либо предложите еще какой вариант.
Если CSaleDelivery::GetList передать эти профили я получу только два. 2 и 3, а new122:profile и new200:profile уже нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без оптимизации кода, по-быстрому так сказать, то примерно так:

```
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;
Loader::includeModule('sale');

$locationCode = '2441'; // именно CODE! не ID.

$result = [];
$deliveries = Bitrix\Sale\Delivery\Services\Table::getList(
    [
        'select' => ['ID', 'NAME']
    ]
)->fetchAll();

foreach($deliveries as $delivery)
{
    if(Bitrix\Sale\Delivery\Restrictions\ByLocation::check($locationCode,[],$delivery['ID']))
    {
        $result[] = $delivery;
    }

}

\Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::dump($result);
```

Comment: По хорошему, надо записи через runtime сразу фильтровать и загружать те что нужны, с нужными полями. Но это вы уж сами напишите, на коленке я вам там не распишу. А написанный ответ тоже рабочий, но не оптимальный.

Answer (score 0):

если по ID можно так:

```
function getLocationDeliveryServices($locationId)
{
    if (is_numeric($locationId)) {
        $arLocationDeliveryServices = [];
        $allDeliveries = CSaleDelivery::GetLocationList(
            array(
                'LOCATION_ID' => $locationId,
                'LOCATION_TYPE' => 'L'
            )
        );
        while ($location = $allDeliveries->Fetch()) {
            if (is_numeric($location['DELIVERY_ID'])) {
                //Записываем ID службы
                $arLocationDeliveryServices[] = $location['DELIVERY_ID'];
            } else {
                //Записываем ID профиля службы
                $profileDeliveryId = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $location['DELIVERY_ID']);
                $arLocationDeliveryServices[] = $profileDeliveryId;
            }
        }

         return (count($arLocationDeliveryServices) > 0) ? $arLocationDeliveryServices : false;
    }

    return false;
}

function getAllActiveDeliveryPricesByLocationIds($arLocationDeliveryServices)
{
    try {
        if (is_array($arLocationDeliveryServices) && count($arLocationDeliveryServices) > 0) {
            $arAllDeliveryPrice = [];
            $arActiveDelivery = \Bitrix\Sale\Delivery\Services\Manager::getActiveList();

            if (count($arActiveDelivery) > 0) {
                foreach ($arActiveDelivery as $id => $arDataDelivery) {
                    if (!empty($arDataDelivery['CONFIG']['MAIN']['DELIVERY_PRICE']) && in_array($arDataDelivery['ID'], $arLocationDeliveryServices)) {
                        $arAllDeliveryPrice[$id]['ID'] = $arDataDelivery['ID'];
                        $arAllDeliveryPrice[$id]['PARENT_ID'] = $arDataDelivery['PARENT_ID'];
                        $arAllDeliveryPrice[$id]['NAME'] = $arDataDelivery['NAME'];
                        $arAllDeliveryPrice[$id]['DESCRIPTION'] = $arDataDelivery['DESCRIPTION'];
                        $arAllDeliveryPrice[$id]['DELIVERY_PRICE'] = $arDataDelivery['CONFIG']['MAIN']['DELIVERY_PRICE'];
                        $arAllDeliveryPrice[$id]['PERIOD_TEXT'] = $arDataDelivery['CONFIG']['MAIN']['PERIOD_TEXT'];
                    }
                }

                return (count($arAllDeliveryPrice) > 0) ? $arAllDeliveryPrice : false;
            }
        }
    } catch (\Bitrix\Main\ArgumentException $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}


$arLocationDeliveryServices = getLocationDeliveryServices($LOCATION_ID);
$arAllActiveDeliveryPrices = getAllActiveDeliveryPricesByLocationIds($arLocationDeliveryServices);
```